# Using fsck to check and repair LUKS encrypted disk?

Tags: linux, fsck, luks

My Ubuntu 11.04 machine uses LUKS encryption for root, swap and home. A routine fsck -n revealed a set of errors I need to repair. fsck requires to unmount the partitions. Before luks I would simply boot from a USB stick and fix run fsck from there. What are the steps to do that for LUKS encrypted partitions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The exact method depends on how you have setup luks, and if you have LVM on top of luks or if you just have a filesystem within the luks volume.

If you don't have LVM in addition to luks then you would probably do something like this.

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/rawdevice somename
fsck /dev/mapper/somename

# or

cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 _dev_sda2
fsck /dev/mapper/_dev_sda2
```

If you used the LVM on LUKS option providied by the Debian/Ubuntu installer, then you'll need to start up LVM.  So `vgchange -aly` after opening the encrypted volume, then run fsck against the `/dev/mapper/lvname`.

(If commands are missing, you may need to do `apt-get install cryptsetup` first. Similarly if you need `vgchange` do `apt-get install lvm`.)

Comment: For whatever reason `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/rawdevice somename` wasn't working out to give me something to run `fsck` on, although it was showing up with `vgscan` just fine after `vgchange -ay` as 'active'... I had to create the raw devices manually with `vgscan --mknodes` and then `fsck` on the logical volume showing up in `vgscan` with `fsck /dev/cryptVG/root` - Hope this helps someone else out there

Comment: Hm, no matter if I use `cryptsetup` or `cryptdisk_start`, I get the same result when I try `fsck`: `/dev/mapper/ext_crypt is in use`. I checked `mount` and it is *not mounted* anywhere.

Answer (score 10):

You need to open the LUKS volume first.

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/(whatever) someName
```

This'll ask you for the password, then create `/dev/mapper/someName`, which is the plaintext device that you can run `fsck` on.  When you're done,

```
cryptsetup luksClose someName
```

will remove the `/dev/mapper/someName` plaintext device, .

Answer (score 1):

The procedure should be the same.

Using a Debian (7.7.0 amd64 netinst, in my case) USB stick, one can go into rescue mode, which should identify the LUKS partition, prompt for a password, and map it. It also identifies and maps any LVM partitions contained therein. If you don't mount the root partition, from the shell prompt you can just `e2fsck -f -c /dev/system_name/partition_name`, etc.

This question is four years old, but I don't think that the procedure has changed.

---

I should point out, though, that doing a `fsck -n` on a mounted filesystem is almost sure to report errors that won't actually exist when you `fsck` it unmounted!

Answer (score 0):

I was using a "live" Debian image on a USB memory stick when I encountered the " is in use" problem with `e2fsck`.  The above answers didn't help me, but here's what I learned: as soon as I decrypted the disk with `cryptsetup`, the live OS automagically mounted the volumes somewhere in /media.  I had to unmount the volumes before e2fsck would run on one of them.